# Multiples ajax al crear un modulo de jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo creado un modulo/plugin en jquery. Este crea coge un select y le inserta los options cogiendo la informacion por ajax.

El problema esta que al crear 2 selects me hace 2 llamadas de ajax.

```
(function ($) {
var property = {
    calendars: {},
    calendarAjax: $()
}
$.fn.scheduler = function (options) {
    var $element = $();
    var method = {
        getCalendars: function () {
            if (Object.keys(property.calendars).length < 1) {
                if (typeof property.calendarAjax.done === 'undefined') {
                    property.calendarAjax = $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '/cals/CalendarList',
                        dataType: 'JSON'
                    }).then(function (r) {
                        var lendars = {};
                        $.each(r['calendars'], function (k, v) {
                            if (typeof v !== 'undefined') {
                                lendars[v['id']] = v;
                            }
                        });
                        property.listCalendars = lendars;
                    }, 'JSON');
                }
            }
            if (property.calendarAjax.done()) {
                property.calendarAjax = $.Deferred();
            }
        }
    }

    $element = $(this);
    return {
        selectPickerCalendar: function () {
            method.getCalendars();
            property.calendarAjax.then(function () {
                $element.selectCalendars({
                  listCalendars: property.listCalendars
                });

            });

        }
    }
}})(jQuery);
```

Y si lo llamo dos veces del modo:

```
$('#selec1').scheduler().selectPickerCalendar();
$('#selec2').scheduler().selectPickerCalendar();
```

entonces me hace 2 llamadas al servidor ya que en el segundo todavía no ha tenido tiempo ha obtener respuesta y vuelve a hacer la llamada.

Entonces, estaba pensando en algún `!ifAjaxIsCompleted()` y pasarle algún identificador de conexión o un deferred que sea global pero como veis, es lo que he intentado.

Alguna idea?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Has probado a cargar las propiedades en una variable y después darselas a los dos select?

Comment: @IñigoIrigoyenErquicia lo siento, no te acabo de entender del todo. Dices de coger el ajax y luego crear los selects?

Comment: Si, sería crear las propiedades con los datos obtenidos desde el ajax y después dar esas propiedades a los selects.

Comment: Qué es `selectCalendars`? No aparece definido en tu plugin. ¿Es otro plugin? Tienes el link?

Comment: Si @amenadiel es uno creado por mi, lo que hace es llenar el select con lo que le digo. Necesitas algo parecido?

Comment: Podrías postear el código de `selectCalendar` pero hazlo en un jsfiddle o codepen para no ensuciar tu pregunta. Lo que quiero es replicar tu problema. Además, nos puedes pegar la respuesta que recibes de tu llamada ajax? Por otro lado, no entiendo por qué reasignas ` property.calendarAjax = $.Deferred();`

Comment: Pues si, [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/3kgxvy28/18/) esta lo que no entiendo es por que solo me hace una vez el ajax :S. El `$.Deferred` lo hago para que me funcionen las funciones `.then()` y `.done()`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes modificar tu plug-in para que funcione con selectores múltiples, como:

`$('#selec1, #selec2').scheduler().selectPickerCalendar();`

Me parece el comportamiento "normal" para jQuery.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, lo tenia puesto así, el problema es que los dos select tienen características diferentes y los inicializare con opciones diferentes. Por ello he necesitado separarlo

Comment: No tengo claro que pretendes. Si los select van a depender de lo que recuperes por ajax entonces cada select ha de hacer su propia llamada (dos select, dos ajax); si los select dependen de otras propiedades/condiciones siempre puedes pasarlas por parámetro si no son directamente accesibles desde el plug-ing, quedaría como `.selectPickerCalendar(opciones)` siendo `opciones` un array u objeto para tantos select como necesites (por ejemplo).

Comment: Creo que algo de razon tienes. Mi idea principal es que los objetos pudieran compartir la misma fuente informacion sin tener que estar pidiendola cada vez que se incia. Pero o el ajax esta fuera o han de ser el mismo objeto con propiedades diferentes